# How to use QAndroidJniObject to call Java code from inside Qt?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qandroidjniobject

Starting from an empty Qt for Android project, created with Qt Creator, how do I execute native Java code?

For example, if I have this java method:

```
class HelloJava {
    public static String sayHello(int a, int b) {
        return "Hello from Java, a+b=" + (a+b);
    }
}
```

And I have this Qt method which should call the `HelloJava.sayHello()` method:

```
QString call_HelloJava_sayHello(int a, int b) {
    // What goes in here?
}
```

Where do I put the Java code in my project, and what goes inside the `call_HelloJava_sayHello()` method?

Comment: Also, this was published just the other day: http://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Qt doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html) is pretty verbose on the subject:

```
// Java class
package org.qtproject.qt5;
class TestClass
{
   static String fromNumber(int x) { ... }
   static String[] stringArray(String s1, String s2) { ... }
}


// C++ code

// The signature for the first function is "(I)Ljava/lang/String;"
QAndroidJniObject stringNumber = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/TestClass",
                                                                           "fromNumber"
                                                                           "(I)Ljava/lang/String;",
                                                                           10);

// the signature for the second function is "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;"
QAndroidJniObject string1 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("String1");
QAndroidJniObject string2 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("String2");
QAndroidJniObject stringArray = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/TestClass",
                                                                          "stringArray"
                                                                          "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;"
                                                                           string1.object<jstring>(),
                                                                           string2.object<jstring>());
```

So the sig of your function should be `"(I;I;)Ljava/lang/String;"`

And also this:

> ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR: This variable can be used to specify a
>   directory where additions and modifications can be made to the default
>   Android package template. The androiddeployqt tool will copy the
>   application template from Qt into the build directory, and then it
>   will copy the contents of the ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR on top of
>   this, overwriting any existing files. The update step where parts of
>   the source files are modified automatically to reflect your other
>   settings is then run on the resulting merged package. If you, for
>   instance, want to make a custom AndroidManifest.xml for your
>   application, then place this directly into the folder specified in
>   this variable. You can also add custom Java files in
>   ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR/src.
>
> Note: When adding custom versions of the build files (like
>   strings.xml, libs.xml, AndroidManifest.xml, etc.) to your project,
>   make sure you copy them from the package template, which is located in
>   $QT/src/android/java. You should never copy any files from the build
>   directory, as these files have been altered to match the current build
>   settings.

So it seems you need to specify that and the java files are automatically deployed.

Just add this to your .pro file (assuming your java sources are placed at `/path/to/project/myjava/src`:

```
android {
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR=$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/android
    QT += androidextras
}
```

`_PRO_FILE_PWD_` is a qmake variable that will resolve to the project directory.

Comment: can you please tell me where should I place the Java class? becuase when I use my Library as a part from AAR android lib project and I call  Class from AAR project the QAndroidJniObject fails without error printed?

Comment: I would be really thankful if you have time to take a look here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461847/why-creating-qandroidjniobject-from-jobject-fails-without-error