# Call own non static java method from QT/C++

Tags: java, android, qt, java-native-interface

I am trying to call non static method callNative of my own Java class from QT/C++ but I get the following error:

*W System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity;.callNative()V;"*

Here is the code of java class:

```
package com.ieio.finger;


import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Finger extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity {
    public void callNative()
        {
            System.out.println("I am in Java");
        }
}
```

Here the C++ code
finger.h

```
#ifndef FINGER_H
#define FINGER_H

#include <QObject>

class finger : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit finger(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void call_java();
signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // FINGER_H
```

finger.cpp:

```
#include <QtAndroidExtras/QAndroidJniObject>
#include <QtAndroidExtras/QtAndroid>
#include "finger.h"


finger::finger(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void finger::call_java()
{
    qDebug()<< "call java";
    QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("callNative","()V;");
    qDebug()<< "called java";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <finger.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {    
        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
        qmlRegisterType<finger>("io.qt.ieio.finger", 1, 0, "Finger");

        engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
        if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
            return -1;

        return app.exec();
    }
```

and the qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

import io.qt.ieio.finger 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Finger
    {
        id:myFinger
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 234
        y: 284
        text: qsTr("Button")
        onClicked: {
            myFinger.call_java()
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I get  *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Java function from Qt C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655181/calling-java-function-from-qt-c)

Comment: I do not think so, in the link you suggested all the Java function are static.

Comment: the semicolon after `()V` does not belong there.

Comment: yes, right this is a mistake

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I found a solution:
I changed the method:

```
void finger::call_java()
{
    qDebug()<< "call java";
    QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("callNative","()V;");
    qDebug()<< "called java";
}
```

in

```
void finger::call_java()
{
    qDebug()<< "call java";
    QtAndroid::runOnAndroidThread([]{
        QAndroidJniObject myJavaObject("com/ieio/finger/Finger");
        myJavaObject.callMethod<void>("callNative","()V");
    });
    qDebug()<< "called java";
}
```