# Why creating QAndroidJniObject from jobject or jclass or simple QString fails without error?

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

**UPDATE**: Same problem happens when I try to create **QAndroidJniObject** from **jclass**. Class is successfully found but QAndroidJniObject is not created and app crash.

```
 jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/example/MyLib/Person");
 QAndroidJniObject p(cls);
```

This also fails:

```
QAndroidJniObject string = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("TESTSTRING");
```

I have simple example where I try to call Java function from C++ library in android application. First I am building:
**libMyLib.so**, then I am creating **AAR** library which includes the **libMyLib.so** and then I am testing the AAR  in  **new test android app project**.

Inside my Qt library project for libMyLib.so, I have `jniinterface.cpp` and this is the function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_MyLib_LibraryClass_personTest(JNIEnv*, jobject, jobject person)
{
    qDebug() << "C++ lib _________ Creating now QAndroidJniObject";
    QAndroidJniObject p(person);
    p.callMethod<void>("printPersonInfo", "(I)V", 29);
}
```

After `libMyLib.so` is built successfully, I am copying it in my AAR android project in  `My_AAR_project\app\src\main\jniLibs\x86\libMyLib.so`

In this **My_AAR_project** I have two simple classes:
**LibraryClass.java**

```
public class LibraryClass {

    public native void personTest(Person person);

    public void testThePerson() {
        Person p = new Person();
        personTest(p);
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MyLib");
    }
}
```

And the other class is simple **Person.java** class:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person() {}

    public static void printPersonInfo(int n)
    {
        System.out.println("Called printPersonInfo " + " Name: John" + " age: " + n);
    }
}
```

And now after I built successfully AAR lib I am including it in my test android app and I am calling:

```
LibraryClass test = new LibraryClass();
test.testThePerson();
```

And the app crash and the last output is before creation of QAndroidJniObject:

> D/: C++ lib _________ Creating now QAndroidJniObject
>
> A/libc: Fatal
> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 19897
> (ampleandroidapp), pid 19897 (ampleandroidapp)

Any help or hint what may be the problem? Or I am doing something wrong.

To simplify what I am trying to do:

1. Create Person object on java side
2. Pass the Person object to C++ lirary
3. Call `printPersonInfo` function from C++ on the Person object that is received from java

Comment: is it possible problem that my Person and LibraryClass classes are in other package `com.example.MyLib` in my AAR project?

Comment: but it should not be the cause because I am checking before QAndroidJniObject p(person)  with this `person == nullptr ? qDebug() << "person is NULLPTR" : qDebug() << "person is jobject";`     and I am getting that person is jobject

Comment: also is there possible way to see the error or reason why `QAndroidJniObject p(person);`  fails

Comment: Seems strange to me that any `QAndroidJniObject` object can process the `person` Java object without using the passed `JNIEnv*`?  Seems like you're missing something in the documentation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thank you very much for reply. I will try to find  something as you pointed with using JNIEnv* .

Comment: From looking at the documentation, it seems that the `QAndroidJniObject` constructor and methods have to be attaching and detaching the current thread to and from the JVM, which isn't going to work in a JNI thread that's already attached to the JVM.

Comment: I tried now with this in my personTest C function:  `jclass cls = env->FindClass("Person");` and this return nullptr it can not find the Person class